# A function which returns 5 without having any alphabet or number in it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can anybody explain the solutions to [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5-without-alphanums/train/javascript) kata on codewars to me

The instructions are -

> Write a function/proc/lambda called _ that always returns 5.
>
> Sounds easy right? Just bear in mind that you can only use the following characters:
>
> ~!@#$%^&*()-_+=[]{}|:;"'<,>.?/`

How will these solutions work

1. `_=_=>-~-~-~-~-~[]`
2. `_=()=>+!""+!""+!""+!""+!""`

And there are many [other solutions](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5-without-alphanums/solutions) but I am not understanding any of them.

All I understand is that a function named _ is defined. How the expressions, being returned evaluate is beyond me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_=()=>+!""+!""+!""+!""+!""
```

At first this sets up an arrow function named `_` :

```
_=()=>
```

And if that is called it evaluates this:

```
!""
```

An empty string `""` is falsy, its negation (`!`) is truthy so we end up at:

```
 true + true + true + true + true
```

As adding booleans doesnt really work, they are converted to numbers first (`false` -> `0`, `true` -> `1`)

---

```
-~-~-~-~-~[]
```

That is slightly more complicated.

```
~[]
```

That calls the bitwise negation operator onto an empty array. Again, the empty array is converted to a number, by first converting it into a string (`[]` -> `""`) and then parsing that as a number (`""` -> `0`), its negation is the number `2 ^ 32 - 1` (where 32 bits are set). Now doing

```
 ~-
```

on that converts that into a negative number (`-`) and then swaps all bits again. This is repeated until we arrive at `101` in binary.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my question was downvoted by four

Comment: @ammar four people dont understand whats going on there ;)

Comment: Four people think that explanations for codegolf answers are a bit off topic for SO and/or they think that there hasn't been put enough effort in understanding it, for instance by showing that you tried to break up the statements to see what happened.

Comment: @golezTrol i dont quite agree. *SO is the place were developers learn [...]* and the OP definetly wants to learn something. While i agree that asking for a codegolf solution is definetly off-topic, trying to understand it is not imo. And i also think that its hard  figure out whats going on so the usual "show research" rule doesnt really fit here. However thats why i just mentioned keypoints and did not went into detail so tuat the OP can figure out the details on his own...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code, but i am not sure, if logical is correct or not

```
return 'fivee'.length;
```

Comment: I don't think this counts, as it contains alphabetical characters.